Apache redirect url to another url passing parameters
In our use case we want to simplify very complex urls to simpler ones through Apache.
We have a GIS system which we want to link to some Kibana dashboards. We want that when someone clicks on a defined geographic area object on the GIS, a Kibana dashboard is called with some parameters that define the filter for that geographic area.
From an url point of view, this is quite easy, and we have it already working, our GIS builds urls that correctly calls to filtered dashboards, and Kibana interprets them correctly
Now, for security and maintaining purposes, we want to simplify those complex urls and redirect to them through an Apache server. Maybe in the future our dashboard change and the url pointing to it needs also to change, so we want to update that url just once on Apache server better than have to update it on several different possible applications that call it.
So... summarizing
We want to reach complex urls like:
https://our-kibana-domain/bla/ble/bli?param1=fixed_value1&param2=fixed_value2&param3=variable

through an url like:
https://our-kibana-domain/blu?my_only_param=variable

We have reached something more or less like this enabling on our apache server:
<Location /blu>
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://our-kibana-domain/bla/ble/bli$1 [R=301,L]
</Location>

However, that forces us to pass every single param through our simplified url, and forces us to have some parts of the global url which could change on the future in the simplified part, while we would like to enclose them on the redirection.
So, our idea here is to use something that allow us to compose a complex url with a fixed part and a variable part which we take from the simplified url, and redirect to that complex built on the run url when a request to simplified url is made.
Is that even possible? How can be achieved?

Certainly that is possible, why not? As long as all required information is present in the requested URL you can rewrite it however you want. You just have to create a URL structure that can be interpreted by the rewriting process by means of a URL. Maybe something like /blu/<param1>/<param2>/<param3>. Given such structure it would be trivial to parse and rearrange the request. What you can not do is somehow make up those paramters from thin air inside the rewriting process. They have to be part of the originally requested URL.

And in general I would advise to not redirect those requests, but to proxy them instead. Much cleaner from the requesting client's point of view and you don't have to expose that Kibana API at all to the clients.
